# VSTS Private hosted agent locking himself out

Tags: azure-devops

Since I've used my 240 Minutes off a free hosted agent, I decided to set a private one up on my machine.

I pretty much just used the [**`FAQ`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) to set up the Agent and install it was a Windows Service running under my account:
[image]

Unfortunately, whenever I queue a build, I get the following ere:

> Downloading task: NuGetCommand The process cannot access the file
>   '`C:\Users\matthias.mueller\Desktop\Stuff\Privat\Agent\_work\_tasks\NuGetCommand_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\2.0.24\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\CredentialProvider\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`'
>   because it is being used by another process.

I checked and deleted this folder and even wrote a small program, which checks, who is locking this file. But interesting enough, outside of the build process nobody is locking it, so it seems like it is the process itself having a problem?

To be fair, I cant tell much more, since I tried to run the service under several users and also googled similar problems, but I couldn't find anything regarding the lock of certain files. I also restarted the PC, stopped all programs and processes etc., but nothing helped.

Are there some known problems regarding the lock of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please troubleshooting the issue with  below aspects:

1. detect files and folders in use

   You can use the tool like [Proess Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) or [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) etc.
2. Anti-virus exclusion

If you are using MSBuild during your build, please also check with below aspects:

3. MSBuild and `/nodeReuse:false`
4. MSBuild and `/maxcpucount:[n]`

More details, you can refer [File- and folder-in-use errors.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/troubleshooting?view=vsts#file--and-folder-in-use-errors)

Comment: Many thanks for this very helpful link, it was indeed an anti virus application blocking it.