# Queueing a build in Azure DevOps gives me an error "the process cannot access the file..."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

> [error]One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The process cannot access the file 'C:\agent_work\2\s\Src\Web\bin\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll' because it is being used by another process.)) (The process cannot access the file 'C:\agent_work\2\s\Src\Web\bin\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll' because it is being used by another process.)

I used to be able to queue builds; this just now started erroring out today. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49454090/4629442) has the same symptoms. Are you running on-prem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by on-prem but we are using a self-hosted agent; is that the same thing? So you think it might be antivirus software on the machine running the agent?

Comment: I don't think having a self-hosted agent is exactly the same thing as running all of Azure DevOps on-prem (known as Azure DevOps **Server**), but it can make a difference for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the "Azure Pipelines Agent (MyCompanyName.MyMachineName)" service on the build server solved this for me.

Comment: Good to hear it was a simple fix.

Answer (score -2):

This is because you have committed your `bin` folder to source control. `bin` and `obj` folders should **never** be committed to source control. Remove it and ensure it is never re-added by making an appropriate `.tfignore` or `.gitignore` depending on whether you are using Git or TFVC for source control.

Comment: No, `bin` and `obj` are already excluded from source control. Thanks, though!